# Support for multiple environments in your windows store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have been working on a Windows Store app where I have to support multiple configuration parameters for my app. One of the parameters is the URL the app is talking to.

For example development environment, test, acceptance and finally production.

One of the things i'm currently thinking about is what is the most efficient way of supporting all these environments with the least effort. Because there isn't some kind of config file that we can change to update these parameters I came up with some ideas. I'm curious about other options that I might have not seen.

Here are the things I came up with:

**1**

Adding multiple configuration to the app and than using them in code to get the correct parameter like this:

```
        private string webserviceUrl;
#if DEV
        webserviceUrl = "devUrl";
#elif TEST
        webserviceUrl = "testUrl";
#endif
```

**2**

With the approach in number 1 there are a few more options available like including a config xml file bases on the configuration, or fetching configuration settings from a webservice the first time the app is running.

**3**

Using a branch/merge strategy and update the config files in the branch. Advantage is that the code is clean and only contains the settings it needs for the build it's created for. And the package can be build by the build server. Disadvantage is that you need to branch/merge alot.

The last option feels like the most 'clean' solution to do this. Am I missing any options, or do you have experience with any of these methods? What would you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

I think the assumption is that apps in the store will always point to production.

But, in saying that, I'm facing the same issue as we're side loading the application onto devices that we control, and not using the Windows Store at all.

To answer your question, I prefer option 1.
Option 2 and the xml/json config file seems like the best option though.
The webservice option probably won't work.  What webservice URL do you use? And how will it work if you want some instances pointing to different environments as they will all be fetching the config from the same URL.

Another option you might want to consider would be options in the settings charm menu.  For example, use radio buttons for the environments, and allow the user to configure which environment they want to target.

The issue would be locking it down in production for end users so that it isn't modifiable any more.  Perhaps once "PROD" radio is selected, all the radio buttons are then hidden.

If you're deploying the application through side loading, then these settings could probably be configured during the install process.

I'd be interested to hear other opinions as well.  This is also an old question, so I'd like to know what solution you decided on implementing.